# How to get recored creation time in solr?

Tags: apache, solr, indexing, dataimporthandler

I'm using DataImportHandler to index data from Postgres

I would like to get the record creation time so I could compare it to the actual object creation time later

These records are being updated (by id), so adding "NOW" field won't do the trick

Comment: enable Solr timestamp field as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124903/solr4-1-cant-delete-documents-older-than-30-days

Comment: I want the first index time, not the last index time

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it eventually:

1.Use multiValued

schema.xml:

```
<field name="creation_time"  type="date" indexed="false"  stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true" />
```

2. Add FirstFieldValueUpdateProcessorFactory to the update process chain, which will keep only the first value

solrconfig.xml under updateRequestProcessorChain:

```
<processor class="solr.FirstFieldValueUpdateProcessorFactory">
  <str name="fieldName">creation_time</str>
</processor>
```

3. When indexing use solr 4.0 atomic update "add" on this field:

```
{"creation_time": {"add":"2012-03-06T15:02:45.017Z"}}
```

The solution is taken from here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4468